# Retrieval Flickr Groups (IDs) with Photo id using Flickr API

Tags: python, api, flickr

I have got the Flickr photo id, can I find out the photo's corresponding group ids, set ids and pool ids that it belongs to?

I have check the Flickr APIs on https://www.flickr.com/services/api/, but I cannot find a suitable one. Am I missing something?

By the way, I use python Flickr API in: https://github.com/alexis-mignon/python-flickr-api

In summary, I want to know which groups (ids) or sets (ids) or pools (ids) an photo belongs to by using its flickr photo id. Can Flickr API can do it?

Thanks.

Comment: I find that pools seems correspond to groups, sets correspond to albums. The following answer by kpie seems solve my problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use api/flickr.photos.getAllContexts for the sets and pools. 
https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getAllContexts.html

I'm not sure about groups yet, but it is probably on of the flickr.photos.*

```
photos

flickr.photos.addTags
flickr.photos.delete
flickr.photos.getAllContexts           <-
flickr.photos.getContactsPhotos
flickr.photos.getContactsPublicPhotos
flickr.photos.getContext
flickr.photos.getCounts
flickr.photos.getExif
flickr.photos.getFavorites
flickr.photos.getInfo
flickr.photos.getNotInSet
flickr.photos.getPerms
flickr.photos.getRecent
flickr.photos.getSizes
flickr.photos.getUntagged
flickr.photos.getWithGeoData
flickr.photos.getWithoutGeoData
flickr.photos.recentlyUpdated
flickr.photos.removeTag
flickr.photos.search
flickr.photos.setContentType
flickr.photos.setDates
flickr.photos.setMeta
flickr.photos.setPerms
flickr.photos.setSafetyLevel
flickr.photos.setTags
```

Comment: I know you get tags from https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getInfo.html but I don't use flickr so I have no idea if tags and groups are the same thing...

Comment: Thanks, your answer helps a lot. It seems to me that tags and groups are 2 things.

Comment: np, glad I could help.